# Cricle through brackets mapping

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, neovim

I'm using bracket a lot and I'm trying to quickly circle through the bracket in both back and forth with the following mapping:

```
nnoremap 0 f)
nnoremap 9 F(
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! How does it not work? Can you give an example of a sample line of text, where the cursor is, what you pressed, what you expected to happen and what actually happened?

Comment: When I think of cycling through brackets I think of the `%` command. That jumps back and forth between a pair of parens/braces/etc. That doesn't do what you want? Then perhaps you mean that PLUS being able to jump to the next/previous pair...?

Comment: Digits are normally used as "repeat counter". You should never remap them.

Comment: It works for me if I try it; as filbranden said: we need a bit more information on your actual issue here.

Comment: My guess is that the the issue is that `f)` doesn't go to the next line so what OP is looking for is probably a search like `/)` and then `n` and `N`. @logbasex you might also be interested in [`:h ;`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%3b) and [`:h ,`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%2c). But until you edit the question with more details I'll also be voting to close the question as unclear.